# Migration from DB2 10.05 to 10.5 Windows

Tags: azure, db2, sap-erp

We have a DB2 version 10.05.0008 running on Windows 2008R2 in a SAP ECC installation on premise. We want to migrate to cloud using Windows 2016 with DB2 10.5. Is it possible to migrate from 10.05 to 10.5? If yes, what is the correct method to do this?

Comment: Ensure that the target Db2 version is at the __same_or_higher__ version  + fixpack than the source database. (the target must never be a lower Db2 version than the source). if the same operating-system family (i.e. Microsoft Windows Server), then you should be able to do a redirected restore (privided that you have sufficient access to the cloud environment and cloud Db2-instance).  But you must engage suitably competent and also suitably experienced people to do the work if you lack the skills.

Comment: Thanks by the attention Mao!